# Bootstrap 4 Icons cannot be loaded

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, icons

When I am trying to put any icons from Bootstrap in _Layout.cshtml anywhere in the file for example in the footer nothing appears.

I have tried looking at the Bootstrap version, verifying the CDN, clearing cache, and different browsers but nothing works.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - learningProcess1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/learningProcess1.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-dark bg-primary border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">learningProcess1</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Category" asp-action="Index">Category</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer bg-primary text-muted ">
        <div class="container">
            made with by <i class="bi bi-heart"></i> Дейаа
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dme5zta9/ - even though that is not how a jsfiddle should be made, dumping all the HTML including the head content into the HTML editor, it basically already shows the icon working. So what is going wrong for you, we can't tell with just the code you have given, because that appears to work as it should.